# How to create loops for random matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to create a loop so I can create 1000 random 2x2 matrices (in the range between -10 to 10)

so far I have

```
M = matrix(c(z = runif(4,min = -10, max = 10)),
           nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

I tried to use k=1000

```
for (i in 1:k) {
  if (i>=0) print (i) else (print(-i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to incorporate the loop code I provided? My professor wants us to specifically use the code hints he provided -- k=1000, for (i in 1:k),....

Comment: Also because my professor wants us to use the code [eig=eigen(M)] but it's not compatible with the codes you provided

Comment: Try `k <- 1000; out <- vector("list", length = k); for(i in 1:k) { out[[i]] <- matrix(runif(4, min = -10, max = 10), nrow = 2, ncol = 2) }; out` Don't forget to set a seed.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I'll try it right now :)

Comment: I'm not sure why this error keeps popping up when I try to find the eigenvalues of the random matrices.
I used eig=eigen(out) and keeps saying "Error in eigen(out) : non-square matrix in 'eigen'"

Comment: Try `lapply(out, eigen)` - `out` is a list that contains `k` matrices.

Comment: Oh thank you!! So I extracted the two eigenvalues for each matrix with sapply(out, `[[`, "values"). How can I separate the eigenvalues into two groups - the first eigenvalues and the second eigenvalues for each matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need for.loops to achieve that. 
You can do so by using `lapply`. This way you create a list containing the matrices:

```
set.seed(1)
lapply(1:3, function(z) matrix(runif(4, min = -10, max = 10), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
[[1]]
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -4.689827 1.457067
[2,] -2.557522 8.164156

[[2]]
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -5.966361 8.893505
[2,]  7.967794 3.215956

[[3]]
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  2.582281 -5.880509
[2,] -8.764275 -6.468865
```

In order to create 1000 matrices use `1:1000` instead of `1:3`.

If you insist on using a loop you can use Markus' solution from the comments:

```
k <- 1000
out <- vector("list", length = k)
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:k) { 
  out[[i]] <- matrix(runif(4, min = -10, max = 10), nrow = 2, ncol = 2) 
}
out
```